# successive js methods

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I have a JS function that selects some elements based on the parameters

```
function getElement() {
    var scope = document;

    this.by = function(data) {
        for (key in data) {
            if (key == 'id')    scope = scope.getElementById(data.id);
            if (key == 'tag')   scope = scope.getElementsByTagName(data.tag);
        }       
        return scope;
    }
}

function getEl(data) { return new getElement().by(data); }
```

This is called like `getEl(id : 'divId', tag : 'span')` and it would select all spans in the div 'divId'.

Now, I would like to make another function (inside function Element), called style that would change the CSS on all previously selected spans.

Something like

```
function getElement() {
    var scope = document;

    this.by = function(data) {
        for (key in data) {
            if (key == 'id')    scope = scope.getElementById(data.id);
            if (key == 'tag')   scope = scope.getElementsByTagName(data.tag);
        }       
        return scope;
    }

    this.style = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

**I would like to be able to do something like** `getEl({id : 'divId', tag : 'span').style({display : 'none'})`

But this doesn't seem to work and I receive a `getEl({id: "divId", tag: "span"}).style is undefined` error.

ps: this is for learning purposes only, please do not suggest jQuery or other such frameworks! :)

Kind regards!

Comment: "successive js methods" is called chaining

Comment: :) thanks! as you probably figured out JS is pretty new to me.

Comment: By the way, `getElementById` only supported by `Document` object. It will not work on `Element` or `Node`

Comment: Note that `getElementById` returns a single element (if found), but `getElementsByTagName` can return multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getEl` returns the `scope` variable, which is a list of DOM elements, not a reference to `getElement`.  You need to return `this` to be able to do something like `new getElement().by(data).style()`.

```
this.by = function(data) {
    for (key in data) {
        if (key == 'id')    scope = scope.getElementById(data.id);
        if (key == 'tag')   scope = scope.getElementsByTagName(data.tag);
    }       
    return this;
}
```

Then you can do `getEl({id : 'divId', tag : 'span'}).style({display : 'none'})`.

To get the `scope` variable, you can add something like this:

```
this.elements = function(){
    return scope;
}
```

`getEl({id : 'divId', tag : 'span'}).elements()` will return a list of DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to Rocket :)

```
function getElement() {
    this.scope = document;

    this.get = function() {
        return this.scope;
    }

    this.by = function(data) {
        for (key in data) {
            if (key == 'id')    this.scope = this.scope.getElementById(data.id);
            if (key == 'tag')   this.scope = this.scope.getElementsByTagName(data.tag);

        }
        return this;
    }

    this.style = function(data) {
        console.log(typeof(this.scope));
        for (key in data) {
            if (this.scope.length) {
                for (i = 0; i < this.scope.length; i++) {
                    this.scope[i].style[key] = data[key];
                }
            }
            else {
                this.scope.style[key] = data[key];
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
}
function getEl(data) { return new getElement().by(data); }
```

It works with:
`getEl({id : "tara_content", tag : "div"}).style({display : "none"});`
`getEl({id : "tara_content"}).style({display : "none"});`
`getEl({tag : "div"}).style({display : "none"});`

As Mathias Bynens noticed `by()` can return an array of elements or just one element, this is why in `style()` I'm checking for the length of `this.scope`. (I couldn't find any way to force the type).

Thanks for the help! :)